# Admin, two links to different views?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

in django admin the views that show the register's just have 
a link to "edit", but what happen if a need an extra(S) links to 
another views? 
for example: 
i have view that show the list of registered People, the nick is 
linking to the Edit page (the normal way of Django), but i need 
another links that will show me the "articles" of the people and 
another the "comments" of the people. 
how ill make this with django admin? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming some field names from your models to answer)

Make the author field from "comment" searchable:

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ("=author",)
```

Use [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) and HTML to control what's displayed on the people's list admin page:

```
def comments(obj):
    return ('<a href="/admin/pathto/comments/?q=%s">comments</a>' % obj.name)
comments.short_description = 'comments'
comments.allow_tags = True

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", comments,)
```

And change `/admin/pathto/comments/` to whatever your comment's admin list page is.

Basically you're going to direct your users to the comments search result page.

Comment: +1, this is absolutely the right way to do it, except I think it's better to keep the function as a method of the ModelAdmin subclass - in which case it will be `def comments(self, obj)`.